# syntax error with php mail script

Tags: php, email

I have a working contact form. I am trying to convert it to only send a email address from a different form to allow people to subscribe to a mailing list. I don't understand php that well. I am using codev and do not see an errors in my syntax.

This is my code that is working I am using for the contact.php form:

```
<?php

$params = array(
    'to' => 'mail@mail.com', 
    'from' => '<mail@mail.com>' 
);

$name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
$email = trim( $_POST['email'] );
$subject = trim( $_POST['subject'] );
$message = trim( $_POST['message'] );

if ( empty( $name ) or empty( $message ) ) {
    echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'error' ) );
} else if ( empty( $email ) or ! filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
    echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'email' ) );
} else {
    $headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' ' . $params['from'] . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion( );
    $message = str_replace( array( "\r", "\n" ), array( '', "\r\n" ), $message );

    if ( mail( $params['to'], ( empty( $subject ) ? 'New message without subject' : 'New message: ' . $subject ), $message, $headers ) ) {
        echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'ok' ) );
    } else {
        echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'error' ) );
    }
}
?>
```

And This is the new code I am trying to make to send me someones email when they subscribe:

```
  <?php
$params =   ["to" => "recieve@wuno.com", "from" => "noreply@wuno.com"];
$subject    =   "New Subscription";
$message    =   trim($_POST["subscribe"]);


if (empty($message)   || !filter_var($message, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo json_encode(["status" => "email"]);
} else {
    $headers    =   "From: {$params[from]}\r\n";
    $headers    .=  "Reply-To: {$message}\r\n";
    $headers    .=  "X-Mailer: PHP".phpversion()."\r\n";
    $message    =   str_replace(["\r","\n"], ["", "\r\n"], $message);
    if(mail($params["to"], $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo json_encode(["status" => "ok"]);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(["status" => "error"]);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: im working off of my server

Comment: @tchow002 Doesn't matter, it's a syntax error.

Comment: The header `'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion( );` is repeated in your code but I don't think this will cause the problem you describe. Reply-To should be an email address too. What error are you receiving specifically? I haven't tested specifically, but does your `empty( $subject ) ? 'New Subscriber' : 'New message: ' . $subject )` return expected results?

Comment: thats the thing. Its not returning anything. it submits fine and nothing shows up

Comment: to be clear, the form field is posting  name="subscribe" I want to get that in an email and send it to myself. the rest of the code is me using code from a working script i had sending a contact form. ill update the my code again with what I incorporated from sidsters code. Thank you for helping me

Comment: You are sure your code is getting to `mail`? Make an `echo'Mail here';` or something on the line before `mail` in your code

Comment: Of course, you can do an `echo'Here-1';` and later `echo'Here-2';` throughout to see where you are getting to. The equivalent of breakpoints.

Comment: ok im going to echo mail here

Comment: hmm im not seeing any output..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49829/discussion-between-jbes-and-nichodiaz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some variables are actually constants so can be defined beforehand basically for legibility, though could be hardcoded.

```
<?php 
$to='tomail@mail.com';
$from='noreply@mail.com';
$subject='New Subscription'; 
$message=trim($_POST['subscribe']); 

if(!filter_var($message,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo json_encode(["status" => "email"]);
}else{
$headers="From: $from\r\nReply-To: $message\r\nX-Mailer: PHP".phpversion()."\r\n"; 
$message=str_replace(["\r","\n"], ["", "\r\n"], $message); 
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){ 
echo json_encode(["status" => "ok"]); 
}else{ 
echo json_encode(["status" => "error"]); 
}} 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is...

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

take a good look here: [PHP manual for mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

---

```
mail( $params['to'], "New Subscription", $email_message, $headers);
```

$email_message = whatever message you are willing to send...

Answer (score 0):

```
$params =   ["to" => "nichodiaz@gmail.com", "from" => "noreply@wuno.com"];
$subject    =   "New Suscription";
$message    =   trim($_POST["subscribe"]);
$subscribe  =   "???";

if (empty($subscribe)   || !filter_var($subscribe, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo json_encode(["status" => "email"]);
} else {
    $headers    =   "From: {$params[from]}\r\n";
    $headers    .=  "Reply-To: {$message}\r\n";
    $headers    .=  "X-Mailer: PHP".phpversion()."\r\n";
    $message    =   str_replace(["\r","\n"], ["", "\r\n"], $message);
    if(mail($params["to"], $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo json_encode(["status" => "ok"]);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(["status" => "error"]);
    }
}
```

---

This is totally based on your code. Nevertheless I am unable to undestand some variable placements like $subscribe is actually undefined while $message get its value from $_POST["subscribe"], should be other way around, isn't?

I lest formatting intact on your $message var as I think there must be some other purpose for it. BUT how come Reply-To address in headers is filled by $message var... I give up!